# c# using nancy framework

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, nancy

I need to implement many to many relationship. I have 3 table activity  document and ActivityDocument(which is a link table).
These are my tables
Activity-id(pk),Activityname,date, details,ActivityUuid
document-id(pk),name,type,attachment,docuuid
ActivityDocument-id(pk),Docuuid,ActivityUuid
I have to do search and display the list of activity with corresponding attachment of each activities.Here the activity can have one or more attachment.I have to list all the corresponding attachments of particular activity.

```
GET["/meetings",ctx=>ctx.HasQuery("search")]=parameter=> {
    string searchstring=Request.query["Search"];
    string[] strings=searchstring.split(new[]{''});
    sql Query=new sql();
    query.Append("select id,activity,date,details,participants,ActivityUUId from Activity");
    query.Append("where");
    Query.append(Buildwhereclause(strings);
    query.append("order by id desc");
    var results=_db.fetch(<models.meetings>)(query);
    foreach(var meeting in results) {
        List<string>documentmeeting=_db.fetch<string>("select d.attachment from document as d innerjoin documentmeeting as dm on dm.docuuid=d.docuuid innerjoin Activity as A on A.ActivityUuid=dm.Activityuuid");
        meeting.files=documentmeeting;
    }
    return Response.Asjson(results)
}
```

this is my code. Here the problem is , i am getting by hitting the search button i am getting same list of attachments for all the activities.
can any one help me

Comment: Query.append(Buildwhereclause(strings); has unclosed `)` bracket

Comment: ok, that you are right. I tried with bracket .But still its the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a filter for the meeting in the meeting document query:

```
List<string>documentmeeting=_db.fetch<string>("select d.attachment from document as d innerjoin documentmeeting as dm on dm.docuuid=d.docuuid innerjoin Activity as A on A.ActivityUuid=dm.Activityuuid");
```

You are running same query always.